# Why SAS "proc sql" is way too slower than "data step"

Tags: sas

I was trying to calculate past average stock returns. I find using the following "data step" code is much better than using "proc sql" code.

The data step code:

```
%macro same(start = ,end = );
proc sql;drop view temp;quit;

proc sql;
    create table temp
    as select distinct a.*, mean(b.ret_dm) as same_&start._&end, count(b.ret_dm) as sc_&start._&end
    from msf1 as a left join msf1 as b
    on a.stkcd = b.stkcd and &start <= a.ym - b.ym <= &end and a.month = b.month
    group by a.stkcd,a.ym;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table same
    as select a.*, b.same_&start._&end, b.sc_&start._&end
    from same as a left join temp as b
    on a.stkcd = b.stkcd and a.ym = b.ym;
quit;

proc sql; drop table temp;quit;
%mend;

data same; set msf;run;
%same(start = 1,  end = 12);
```

The proc sql code:

```
%macro MA_1;
%do p = 2 %to 9; *;  
    %put p &p;
    proc printto log = junk ; run;      

    proc sql;
        create table price&p
        as select distinct a.*, b.count,b.ym
        from price&p as a left join tradingdate as b
        on a.date = b.date;
    quit;

    proc sort data = price&p; by stkcd ym date;quit;
    data msf;
        set price&p;
        by stkcd ym date;
        if last.ym;
    run;
    proc printto; run;  

    %do j = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&laglist));
        %let lag = %scan(&laglist,&j);
        %put lag &lag;

    /*********************************************/
        proc sql; drop table ma_&lag._&p ;quit;
        %do i = 1 %to 2018; *;
            proc printto log = junk ; run;      
            data getname;
                set stock;
                if _n_ = &i;
                call symput('stkcd',stkcd);
            run;
            proc printto; run;  
            %put &i &stkcd;
            proc printto log = junk ; run;      
            proc sql;
                create table temp
                as select distinct a.*, mean(b.prc) as ma_&lag._&p
                from msf (where = (stkcd = "&stkcd" )) as a left join price&p (where = (stkcd = "&stkcd" )) as b
                on a.stkcd = b.stkcd and 0 <= a.count - b.count <= &lag
                group by a.stkcd, a.date
                order by a.stkcd, a.date;
            quit;

            proc append base = ma_&lag._&p data = temp force; quit; 
            proc printto; run;  
        %end;
        dm "log; clear;";
        proc sql;
            create table ma_allprc
            as select a.*, b.ma_&lag._&p
            from ma_allprc as a left join ma_&lag._&p  as b
            on a.stkcd = b.stkcd and a.date = b.date;
        quit;

        proc sql; drop table ma_&lag._&p;quit;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;

%let laglist = 5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000; *  ;
data ma_allprc; set msf;run;
%ma_1;
```

"Proc sql" is much slower than I thought. "Data step" takes about 3 hours, but "Proc sql" takes about 2 days.

I even have to loop over each stock when using proc sql, cause it takes up too much of the memory space, I have to say that using proc sql to calculate past averages is dumb, but currently I have no better ideas. :(

Does anybody have a solution with that..

Comment: The 'slowness' is all the joining going on for each data point.  If you can use DATA Step, and have or can sort your data, you can write code that uses array to perform these computations and will be faster by a magnitude or more.  Try searching on SAS-L (http://www.listserv.uga.edu/archives/sas-l.html) for "ring array".  If you must use SQL, adding indices for the join variables would let the SQL planner speed things up tremendously.